# Bounding Derivative of a Holomorphic Function on the Unit Disc

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I am trying solve the following problem: Fix $0 < \gamma < 1$ and suppose $f$ is holomorphic on the unit disc satisfying $$|f(z)-f(w)| \le C_1|z-w|^\gamma$$ for some constant $C_1$. Show that there exists a constant $C_2 > 0$ s.t $$|f'(z)| \le C_2(1 - |z|)^{\gamma - 1}$$.

**My attempt:** Since we want to bound the derivative of $f$, I thought it makes sense to use the *Cauchy's Integral Formula*, namely we have: $$|f'(z)| = \frac{1}{2\pi}|\int_{C}\frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^2}dw|,$$  for any circle $C$ around the origin of radius $r < 1$. Using the assumption, we have

\begin{array}{lcl}
|f'(z)| & \le & \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{C}|\frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^2}|dw \\
& \le & \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{C}|\frac{f(w)C_1^{\frac{2}{\gamma}}}{(f(w)-f(z))^{\frac{2}{\gamma}}}| \\
\end{array}

However, this does not look promising, we need to get an exponent $\gamma - 1$. Can someone help me, please?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: This question is a duplicate as shown in the comment above.

To help you find the answer more easily next time, here is the approach0 search I used to find that other question: t.ly/qYls. The first couple of hits weren't what I wanted, but I used ctrl+F for holomorphic and found the right one quickly.